# String.substring() OR operator

Tags: java, string, indexing

Is it possible to perform an OR operator inside of `substring`? Here is what I have but it doesn't work

```
str.substring(str.indexOf("start")+1, str.indexOf("x|y"))
```

Comment: Because I tried and it didn't work as I said in the desecration...

Comment: @Zabuza: You're right. Removed my comment and I'm showing a solution now in my answer.

Comment: You do know that `indexOf("start")+1` is the index to the first `t` in `start`, right? Did you mean `indexOf("start")+5`, i.e. the index of the character immediately after the word `start`?

Comment: Thanks irrelevant I just said that as an example

Answer (score 4):

`indexOf` is not sophisticated enough to do this. You can use regex to get the substring, though:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("start(.*?)(?:x|y)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if (m.find()) {
    String sub = m.group(1);
}
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/eKIGao)

Comment: In regex, I think `(?:x|y)` is better written as `[xy]`. Don't know if there is a performance difference worth noticing, so either form might do, depending on what the end-condition is, but for a choice of single characters, the character class would be better.

Comment: @Andreas Right, for one-character end-markers character class is a winner. I purposely didn't use character class because I'm pretty certain that OP replaced his actual end markers with `"x"` and `"y"`.

Comment: Yes that right I replaced actual markers with x and y to easier readability on SO

Comment: Is there any way at all to do it within str.substring()? just wondering

Comment: @KyrilKhaltesky It seems to me that this is the answer you were looking for? If so, please click the check mark to the left to accept the answer, so others can see that your question has been answered to your satisfaction.

Comment: @KyrilKhaltesky No, `indexOf` cannot do `OR` conditions. You could do multiple `indexOf` calls to search for each end-condition, then pick the lowest index, but regex is so much simpler for what you're doing. Regex is the right tool here, not `indexOf` and `substring`. It's one of the things a good programmer learns: Picking the right tool for the job.

Comment: @KyrilKhaltesky Yes, this could definitely be done with `substring` in the end, but you would need additional logic and multiple calls to `idnexOf`. You could also use regex to locate the index and then grab substring, but that way is too indirect for my taste.

Comment: Sorry just another question, is there a way to do the above but only search for the first `"x"` after `"start"` because at the moment it give me out of bounds error because it searches for an `"x"` before `"start"`

Comment: @KyrilKhaltesky The above code shouldn't give you out of bounds errors, because it does not use `substring`. If you wish to search for the first index of `"x"` and you know that `"start"` begins at index `p`, call `str.indexOf("x", p+5)` where `5` represents the length of string `"start"`.

Comment: I mean at the moment when I use substring and call `str.substring(str.indexOf("start")+1, str.indexOf("x"))` it breaks because there is an x before start, so my question is how I could specifically say search for the first x after start, when the distance between start and x is always different

Comment: @KyrilKhaltesky That's what I tried to explain in my comment. You can't do it on one line, you need to get the index of `"start"` into variable `p`, then use that `p` to obtain `q`, the index of first `"x"` after `p+5`, and finally do the `substring` between `p` and `q`.

Answer (score -1):

Solution:

```
-> "startthexstrayingx".replaceAll ("start([^xy]*(x|y)).*", "$1") 
|  Expression value is: "thex"
|    assigned to temporary variable $72 of type String
```

The first group starts behind the "start" and captures until the first x or y are met.

With a anchor for the String start, it will capture only one match, regardless of the name replaceAll:

```
-> "startstartthexstrayingstartAgainandynotyy".replaceAll ("^start([^xy]*(x|y)).*", "$1") 
|  Expression value is: "startthex"
|    assigned to temporary variable $77 of type String
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/OkOBPH)

Taking the question literally, the pattern has to be `"^s(tart[^xy]*(x|y)).*"` but I suspect that wasn't intended.

But not that way:

```
-> String str = "startthex|ystray"
|  Modified variable str of type String with initial value "startthex|ystray"
|    Update overwrote variable str

-> str.substring(str.indexOf("start")+1, str.indexOf("x|y"))
|  Expression value is: "tartthe"
|    assigned to temporary variable $62 of type String

-> String str = "startthexstray"
|  Modified variable str of type String with initial value "startthexstray"
|    Update overwrote variable str

-> str.substring(str.indexOf("start")+1, str.indexOf("x|y"))
|  java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException thrown: begin 1, end -1, length 14
|        at String.checkBoundsBeginEnd (String.java:3119)
|        at String.substring (String.java:1907)
|        at (#98:1)
```